# Why are Rails validations not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm following the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) to create a very vanilla validation. I've created a callback that works fine, but the validates:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  validates :name, :presence => true

end
```

results in:

```
undefined method `  validates' for #<Class:0x007fa57b1a9e60>
```

This is Rails 3.2.13 with the following gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'pg'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'strong_parameters'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 2.3.0.0'
gem 'devise', '>= 2.2.3'
gem 'cancan', '>= 1.6.9'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'friendly_id', "~> 4.0.9"

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Comment: For kicks, try `validates_presence_of :name`. Also, is that all the code for your model? Where is your `attr_accessible`/`attr_protected` attributes?

Comment: That works, thanks.  I'm using strong parameters, so no model level whitelist/blacklist.  Controllers manage the allowed parameters.

Comment: Ahh didn't think about that. Glad it worked for you. I moved my comment to an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Use `validates_presence_of :name`.

Comment: Why would that work? Rails 3.2 convention is what the OP has already got.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm using strong parameters, so no model level whitelist/blacklist. Controllers manage the allowed parameters. – RyanW

Comment: I'm with sscirrus, not sure why the 3.2 convention is not working. But, moving on with validates_presence_of.  @jason328 Are you saying it's related to attr_accessible/protected?  I created a new, vanilla rails app that used that, and still had the same error.